# What are CN, OU, DC in an LDAP search?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

I have a search query in LDAP like this. What exactly does this query mean?

```
("CN=Dev-India,OU=Distribution Groups,DC=gp,DC=gl,DC=google,DC=com");
```

Comment: It does not work, You do not have a proper LDAP Query. What you have is a fully distinguished name probably from a Active Directory Entry.

Perhaps you should explain what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: check this https://www.rlmueller.net/LDAP_Binding.htm#:~:text=The%20moniker%20%22cn%22%20means%20Common%20Name.%20moniker%20%22dc%22,As%20an%20example%2C%20the%20Distinguished%20Name%20%22cn%3DJoe%20Smith%2Cou%3DEast%2Cdc%3DMyDomain%2Cdc%3Dcom%22

Answer (score 1045, accepted):

- `CN` = Common Name
- `OU` = Organizational Unit
- `DC` = Domain Component

These are all parts of the X.500 Directory Specification, which defines nodes in a LDAP directory.

You can also read up on [LDAP data Interchange Format (`LDIF`)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LDAP_Data_Interchange_Format), which is an alternate format.

You read it from right to left, the right-most component is the root of the tree, and the left most component is the node (or leaf) you want to reach.

Each `=` pair is a search criteria.

With your example query

```
("CN=Dev-India,OU=Distribution Groups,DC=gp,DC=gl,DC=google,DC=com");
```

In effect the query is:

From the `com` Domain Component, find the `google` Domain Component, and then inside it the `gl` Domain Component and then inside it the `gp` Domain Component.

In the `gp` Domain Component, find the Organizational Unit called `Distribution Groups` and then find the object that has a common name of `Dev-India`.

Comment: These are all part of the X.500 Directory specification, Distinguised Name component. Nothing specifically to do with LDIF at all. LDIF is not "how the LDAP tree is 'filtered'": that's the LDAP syntax specification, which is another thing altogether.

Comment: TIL X.509 is an extension of X.500, eg TLS is based on LDAP :grumpycat: (This is a huge oversimplification)

Comment: @EJP How do I ask for several objects by their CN? Like if I want `Dev-India2` along with `Dev-India`?

Comment: @arrowd read https://ldap.com/ldap-filters/. You could use the OR operator (a pipe follwed by the entries) or the SUBSTRING operator (star operator).
OR > `(|(cn=Dev-India2)(cn=Dev-India))`
SUBSTRING > `(cn=Dev-India*)`

Answer (score 580):

**What are CN, OU, DC?**

From [RFC2253 (UTF-8 String Representation of Distinguished Names)](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2253.txt):

> ```
> String  X.500 AttributeType
> ```

```
------------------------------
CN      commonName
L       localityName
ST      stateOrProvinceName
O       organizationName
OU      organizationalUnitName
C       countryName
STREET  streetAddress
DC      domainComponent
UID     userid
```

**What does the string from that query mean?**

The string (`"CN=Dev-India,OU=Distribution Groups,DC=gp,DC=gl,DC=google,DC=com"`) is a path from an **hierarchical structure** ([DIT = Directory Information Tree](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4512#section-2.1)) and should be read from **right** (root) **to left** (leaf).

It is a **DN** (Distinguished Name) (a series of comma-separated key/value pairs used to identify entries uniquely in the directory hierarchy). The DN is actually the entry's fully qualified name.

Here you can see an example where I added some more possible entries.
The actual path is represented using green.

[image: LDAP tree]

The following paths represent DNs (and their value depends on what you want to get after the query is run):

- `"DC=gp,DC=gl,DC=google,DC=com"`
- `"OU=Distribution Groups,DC=gp,DC=gl,DC=google,DC=com"`
- `"OU=People,DC=gp,DC=gl,DC=google,DC=com"`
- `"OU=Groups,DC=gp,DC=gl,DC=google,DC=com"`
- `"CN=QA-Romania,OU=Distribution Groups,DC=gp,DC=gl,DC=google,DC=com"`
- `"CN=Dev-India,OU=Distribution Groups,DC=gp,DC=gl,DC=google,DC=com"`
- `"CN=Diana Anton,OU=People,DC=gp,DC=gl,DC=google,DC=com"`

Comment: Any idea why you may get an empty remaining name? For [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39372374/5606016) there is actually an open bounty on it

Comment: @ROMANIA_engineer, if I am logged in my windows machine (client) where can I get this information?

Comment: I know this post is quite old, yet, for the googlers (like me) that search for an answer on @ArtanisZeratul question for the information:    [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/22866/how-can-i-determine-my-user-accounts-ou-in-a-windows-domain) helped me on that, if you look for the servers just try with nslookup: `nslookup -type=srv _ldap._tcp.MY.DOMAIN`

Comment: Also, for those that need deeper information about the structure of the AD they're in (and do not have something like an Admin Console to look it up) you can use the ADSI editor provided by Windows (access via MMC) - [how to access ADSI Edit](https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.HOWTO9340.html)

Comment: Note that RFC2253 is obsolete, it was superceded in 2006 by RFC4514. It doesn't matter for the list of attribute types quoted, but generally obsolete RFCs shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 27):

I want to add somethings different from definitions of words. Most of them will be visual.

Technically, LDAP is just a protocol that defines the method by which directory data is accessed.Necessarily, it also defines and describes how data is **represented** in the directory service

Data is represented in an LDAP system as a hierarchy of objects, each of which is called an **entry**. The resulting tree structure is called a **Directory Information Tree (DIT)**. The top of the tree is commonly called the **root** (a.k.a base or the suffix).**[image: the Data (Information) Model]**

To navigate the **DIT** we can define a path (a **DN**) to the place where our data is (cn=DEV-India,ou=Distrubition Groups,dc=gp,dc=gl,dc=google,dc=com will take us to a unique entry) or we can define a path (a DN) to where we think our data is (say, ou=Distrubition Groups,dc=gp,dc=gl,dc=google,dc=com) then search for the attribute=value or multiple attribute=value pairs to find our target entry (or entries).

[image]

If you want to get more depth information, you visit [here](https://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch2/index.html#history)

Answer (score 1):

At least with Active Directory, I have been able to search by DistinguishedName by doing an LDAP query in this format (assuming that such a record exists with this distinguishedName):

```
"(distinguishedName=CN=Dev-India,OU=Distribution Groups,DC=gp,DC=gl,DC=google,DC=com)"
```