# default base for LDAP for user verification/authentication

Tags: ldap

What could be the base for LDAP? If there is not any base given during configuration.

I have to verify/authenticate user from a web based application and I have the java code.

```
    String username = "user";
    String password = "password";
    String base = "ou=People,dc=objects,dc=com,dc=au";
    String dn = "uid=" + username + "," + base;
    String ldapURL = "ldap://ldap.example.com:389";
```

but I need to set up the base (variable) for that, I have asked the other team to tell me the base, they said we have not customized anything on LDAP. What could be the default base for LDAP?

Comment: see also a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18756688/what-are-cn-ou-dc-in-an-ldap-search

Comment: @user2314737 Related question; partially wrong answer.

Comment: @EJP Is there any public online ldap server? so that i can check my code is running or not.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>    String base = "ou=People,dc=objects,dc=com,dc=au";
> ```
>
> i need to set up the base (variable) for that, i have asked the other team to tell me the base, they said we have not customized anything on LDAP.

So in that case they are using the default base. In either case they can tell you what it is. Nobody else can: it depends which LDAP server you're using for a start, which you haven't disclosed. We can only guess.

Comment: Is there any public online ldap server? so that i can check my code is running or not?

Comment: I believe so, try Google, but if you don't have your own LDAP server why are you writing this code? and what is this 'other team' doing?

Comment: We have our own LDAP server and that is under the ""Other Team". Actually i am working on a project in which i have to verify/authenticate the user from LDAP. I dont want to make random guesses, so thats why i am writing this code and exactly tell them what kind of information i need from them.

Comment: You already know that. You need to know the base DN of the DIT (Directory Information Tree). Testing against a different LDAP server isn't going to address that by one iota.