# Configuring LDAP On Local Network

Tags: ldap

I am trying to setup an LDAP server for contacts on my local network using an Ubuntu box.  I am confused about the *'dc'* component of the configuration.  Should I set this to localhost if this is the machine I intend to store the contacts on.  Where can I find more descriptive information on how the domain plays into the configuration

Answer (score 0):

The `dc` part is the domainComponent. You would typically want to set this to something that uniquely identifies your company, such as `dc=MyCompany,dc=local`. See the following question for a more complete description of these components: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33961313/2242593

Comment: Okay I See.  Does anyone know of a tutorial on setting up a LDAP server and connecting outlook to it??

Comment: Outlook, so far as I know anyway, is only AD aware. Unless you're configuring/setting up a Samba server of sorts (even then I doubt it would work) you'll need to setup a domain with a Windows server configured as a DC.