# How to connect to ldap data source other than Active Directory from c# code?

Tags: c#

I am looking to connect and retrieve data from ldap data source other than Active Directory. I tried using DirectoryEntry but its meant for Active Directory objects and so doesn't seem to work with others. Are there any other options in c# to connect and fetch data from ldap sources?

Answer (score 0):

```
    DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(LDAP://127.0.0.1/CN=Users,dc=test,dc=com", UserName, Password, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
        DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(de);
         ds.FindOne();
```

1. Replace "127.0.0.1" by your IP.
2. UserName= LDAP User Name
3. Passwoed =LDAP User Password.
4. DC(Domain Component)= your domain component
5. CN (Common Name) = your Common Name
This code works for me to connect LDAP server.

more [What are CN, OU, DC in an LDAP search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18756688/what-are-cn-ou-dc-in-an-ldap-search)