# DirectorySearcher: How to get only entries for "real" users

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, user-accounts, directorysearcher

I use a `DirectorySearcher` to get all users from Active Directory - but I need to get only "real" users.

Filter:

```
search.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))";
```

but I get all user accounts, like:

```
henry.miller            <-wanted
ernest.hemingway        <-wanted
HealthMailboxced7671    <-not wanted
```

**Question:** how does my filter need to be modified to return only *real* users?

My whole code:

```
string DomainPath = "LDAP://DC=writers,DC=local";
DirectoryEntry searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry(DomainPath);
DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot);
search.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))";
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("samaccountname");

SearchResult result;

SearchResultCollection resultCol = search.FindAll();

if (resultCol != null)
{
    for (int counter = 0; counter < resultCol.Count; counter++)
    {
        result = resultCol[counter];

        if (result.Properties.Contains("samaccountname"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine((String)result.Properties["samaccountname"][0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this filter - `(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(SAMAccountName=*)(!(homeMDB=*NonUser*)))`

Comment: Just noticed one typo in above, use `sAMAccountName` instead of `SAMAccountName`. Also try by LDAP - `(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=*)(!(cn=*O*)))`

Comment: I think it is CN only and it is different from distinguishedName

Answer (score 3):

Try below using LDAP

```
 (&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=*)(!(cn=*O*)))
```

Just for info - CN is Common Name. You can get more info on LDAP [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18756688/what-are-cn-ou-dc-in-an-ldap-search/18756876)

You also asked me with what property can you retrieve cn. Here you can extract by this code snippet ( for double check). But as far as I know it is CN only

```
 foreach (string property in result.Properties.PropertyNames)
{
      foreach (Object propertyValue in result.Properties[property])
     {
        // print out the Property Value here
      }
}
```

Comment: sorry prany, does not work. It only removes common names with an "O"; also wanted names like "thomas"

Comment: @boboes - There must be a domain name, right ? so you can filter by `(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=*)(mail = *@Yourdomain.com))`

Comment: HealthMailboxfbff1f1a718e4874917d7e39076275bd@writers.local

Comment: @boboes - Is this the output ?

Comment: infact the users I don't want seem to be real users without any differences and I have to accept them when an exchange server is installed.

Comment: Give it a try on this one - `&(objectClass=user)(cn=" + username + ");`

Comment: @boboes: If your admin has created those mailboxes as real users, there is no way to tell the difference in the AD.  I recommend trying the AD Explorer created way back by Mark Russinovich to see if you can find any properties that you can use to distinguish the two types of users: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/adexplorer