# Keycloak: only allow access to a specific group from Azure AS (Identity Provider)

Tags: azure-active-directory, keycloak

I have a Keycloak and an AzureAD instance that is connected, but I only want people on the AzureAD with the group "App-User" to be able to use my app. How does this work?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `App-User` a group made in keycloak ? If you want to connect to particular user group in ldap then below is the configuration.

You need to add to Users DN in keycloak admin UI.

```
OU=App-User
```

Check out this link for more [AD information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18756688/what-are-cn-ou-dc-in-an-ldap-search)

Comment: No, the "App-User" comes from AD, and if the user does not have this group we will not let the user register in keycloak / access the app

Comment: ok, i have answered it accordingly. can you tell me what have you input in Users DN in keycloak ?

Comment: Ah, I use Identity provider, not user federation! is user federation more suited for this work?

Comment: Identity provider is something when user wants to login via social accounts or something e.g. stackoverflow provides us different identity providers like google facebook etc. https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_ldap